Adding a directory to PATH on tcsh - setenv error
Disclaimer: I am a biologist and have no background in computer science therefore my question may be very stupid.
I installed a software called EMAN2 on a linux system (Fedora, tcsh shell).
To be able to use this software I need to add it to PATH which I am unable to do.
I modified my .cshrc file and added the following command -
setenv PATH $PATH\ /home/cryosparc_user/EMAN2/bin
To execute the .cshrc file , I run source ~/.cshrc
And it returns > setenv: Too many arguments
What could have gone wrong?
I have tried a few different syntaxes, and a few differnt commands like set instead of setenv etc. I am expecting to see my newly installed software in PATH upon executing echo $PATH but it is not there.

Your error suggests you are executing something like
setenv PATH $PATH /home/cryosparc_user/EMAN2/bin

But PATH is a colon-separated list of directories, so you should have something like
setenv PATH $PATH:/home/cryosparc_user/EMAN2/bin


Thank you!! However, I have another \ in this : setenv PATH $PATH\ /home/cryosparc_user/EMAN2/bin is the <> incorrect?

Yes; it escapes the newline so that the result is the same as what I show in the answer.

Hi This didn't help , unfortunately :(. Upon reading up a bit I realized that the fact that EMAN2 directory itself has multiple folders in it can cause this issue. However it is just how it got downloaded.....

It helped, in that you weren't correctly modifying the value of PATH before. That doesn't mean you don't have additional problems.
